# SICP Exercise 2.5 - selector behaves inconstantly

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, scheme, numerical-methods, sicp

I'm reading SICP and doing exercise 2.5:

> [Exercise 2.5.](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%25_thm_2.5)  Show that we can represent pairs of nonnegative
>   integers using only numbers and arithmetic operations if we represent
>   the pair `a` and `b` as the integer that is the product `2^a*3^b`.
>   Give the corresponding definitions of the procedures `cons`, `car`,
>   and `cdr`.

Here is my solution:

```
;;; Exercise 2.5
;;; ============

(define (cons x y)
  (* (expt 2 x)
     (expt 3 y)))

(define (car z)
  ; n is a power of 2, which is greater than z
  (let ((n (expt 2 (ceiling (/ (log z) (log 2))))))
   (/ (log (gcd z n)) (log 2))))

(define (cdr z)
  ; n is a power of 3, which is greater than z
  (let ((n (expt 3 (ceiling (/ (log z) (log 2))))))
   (/ (log (gcd z n)) (log 3))))
```

My code works well with relatively small test cases:

```
(define x 12)
(define y 13)
(define z (cons x y))

(car z)
;Value: 12.
(cdr z)
;Value: 12.999999999999998
```

However, it produces incorrect results when the number grows bigger:

```
(define x 12)
(define y 14)
(define z (cons x y))

(car z)
;Value: 12.
(cdr z)
;Value: 2.8927892607143724 <-- Expected 14
```

I want to know what's wrong with my implementation. Is there anything wrong with the algorithm? The idea is that the greatest common devisor of `z = 2 ^ x * 3 ^ y` and `n` (a power of 2 which is greater than `z`) is exactly `2 ^ x`.

If my algorithm is correct, is this inconsistency caused by a rounding error and/or an overflow?

Comment: There's an asymmetry to your definitions which looks wrong. I suspect that you wrote `cdr` using copy-and-paste.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes I did, for I think they are analogous. Both `car` and `cdr` use `(ceiling (/ (log z) (log 2)))`, because for `z=2^x*3^y`, `log_2(z)` would be greater than both `x` and `y`, while `log_3(z)` is only guaranteed to be greater than `y`.

Comment: @SunQingyao I just changed `2` to `3` in the definition of `cdr` and I actually get 14.0 instead of 2.89 so it seems to have an effect.

Comment: @Sylwester IOW you've found a typo, that affected the non-coprime powers cases (and not the big numbers cases :) ); still, `(car (cons 31 37))` does not return 31.0.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to avoid floating point numbers.

Consider `max-power-dividing` which finds the maximal exponent `k` such that `p^k` divides `n`:

```
(define (max-power-dividing p n)
  (if (zero? (remainder n p))
      (+ 1 (max-power-dividing p (/ n p)))
      0))
```

Then we can write:

```
(define (car z) (max-power-dividing 2 z))
(define (cdr z) (max-power-dividing 3 z))
```

As far as I can tell, your solution uses the right idea, but the floating point computation breaks for large numbers.

Comment: Thank you for providing another solution to this question. However, I would like to improve my solution, rather than simply using others' solution. Anyway, debugging is half the fun of coding. So, please tell me how to force MIT-Scheme not to use floating-point computation.(Also, my algorithm seems to have a theta-of-log(n) order of growth, while yours has a theta-of-n order of growth...)

Comment: @SunQingyao I expect `log` is necessarily floating point, but you can check the docs. as for the efficiency, you can improve upon the code given here, by a standard trick of *doubling* at each step of iteration.